# Passing DataGridView selected value to a text box

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
Private Sub DataGridViewMachine_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewMachine.CellContentClick
    frmAddNewWrkReq.txtbxAssetName.Text = DataGridViewMachine.SelectedRows(DataGridViewMachine.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value.ToString
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

How do I get the selected value from the datagridview on to the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
frmAddNewWrkReq.txtbxAssetName.Text = DataGridViewMachine.CurrentRow.Cells("name_of_the_cell").Value.ToString
```

May be necessary set `SelectMode=FullRowSelect` on DataGridViewMachine

Comment: I tried code above. Works, no errors. Make sure you have the correct names of controls. You get any error message?

Comment: Thanks.I'll try it and see

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
frmAddNewWrkReq.txtbxAssetName.Text = DataGridViewMachine.Rows(DataGridViewMachine.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(1).Value.ToString
```